Firebase Admin SDK: Create custom auth token with Cloud Functions v2
In my firebase project I have upgraded functions from v1 to v2. Suddenly creating a custom auth token fails with:

FirebaseAuthError: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob' denied on resource (or it may not exist).; Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens for more details on how to use and troubleshoot this feature.

I am calling getAuth().createCustomToken(uid).
Do I need to fix permission configuration? How do I add the missing permission? Where do I have to add it to? My service account already has the role "Service Account Token Creator". And this role already contains 'iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob'.
Or do I have to use the APIs differently in functions 2nd Gen?

i redid all the steps from the docs as well, and no luck. same problem. Any solution found?

As functions v2 runs via cloud run, the service account seems to be pinned to a different one: XXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
No matter which account I set in initializeApp(), it kept ignoring this.
Set the Service Account Token Creator permission for the account used for Cloud Run Invoker and it should work.
